# cgi-bin : What's the importance of cgi-bin folder in web security and application development

Tags: web-applications, security, cgi-bin

Most famous and wide using website( like https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/) are using cgi-bin folder to place there files. Is any importance to use `cgi-bin` folder in web application development or get any kind of security to put files in cgi-bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding PayPal, I believe that have done it because their site was initially built on the basis of Per web application that were traditionally built using cgi technology.

Generally, for the purpose of extra-security measures its better to place all of your code (classes, interfaces, functioncts, third-party libraries, etc) outside your DOCUMENT_ROOT folder. It is especially important when your application is divided into several parts - like controller, model, view, templates because prevents the malicious user from trying to call each part of the application separately when he is looking for vulnerabilities. It also important for files that store sensitive data, e.g. database credentials - you do not want them to be fetched by a hacker. By moving everything from DOCUMENT_ROOT into cgi-bin folder you do not gain much of a security since the everything in cgi-bin folder has to be accessible from the Web and thus a hacker can still call/open any file residing in them. It would be much better to move the code and sensitive files off to a directory not available from the web and leave only the file with the entering point to the application (index.php, for example). as well as static resources (Javascript, image files, etc.) in it.